# Dojo Dialog not loading with style

Tags: javascript, openlayers, dojo

I'm trying to use dojo dialog dijit, but it's loading without style. I mean, the claro theme is not being applied to the dialog.

I'm also using openlayers on the page, and for some reason, the style does not load.

My dojo import has parseOnLoad = true and this is the code used to create the dialog:

```
        var dialog = new dijit.Dialog({
            id:"servicesDialog",
            title: "Serviços",
            style: "width:300px;background-color:white;padding:25px;",
            content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        });

        dialog.show();
```

[image: dialog without style]

I want the dialog to come up with the dojo style. Why this is not working?

EDIT: my guess is that the ordering that openlayers uses is being screwed up by the dialog. Hence screenshot #2. The square point is on top of the dialog.

[image: feature from map overlaying dialog div]

Thanks

Comment: show us some more code - your `<style>` and `<link>` tags in main html file for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would speculate that you didn't include a theme.  Add the following css and add the theme to the body.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
</head>
<body class="claro">
```